# Raspberry PI with HKpilot32

Tags: raspberry-pi, ardupilot

I would like to connect my RP3 to the HKpilot. While most connections are pretty [straightforward](http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/raspberry-pi-via-mavlink.html), I would like to know how ca I power the PI:

1. It is stated in the above link that "The RPi can be powered by connecting the red V+ cable to the +5V pin", can the HK32 pilot deal with the power consumption of th RP?
2. It is also stated that "The RPi can be powered ... from USB in", in this case, there is the grouding is shared? From where can I get a 5v  output? Do I need to build a voltage regulator?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I would not attempt to power the Pi directly from the flight controller. The last thing you want is to have unexpected power demands crash your vehicle.

The easiest solution is probably to grab a 5v BEC (if you don't already have a regulated 5v supply available from one of your ESCs or from your power distribution board) and wire that to the appropriate GPIO pins.

You're slightly better off if you power the Pi via the USB port, because this will keep the Pi's own voltage regulator and fuse in the loop.  To do this you would simply need to wire a microUSB connector to your 5v power supply.  [ModMyPi](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-do-i-power-my-raspberry-pi) has some more in-depth recommendations on the topic of powering a Pi.